# Issue in reading data in UART port in beaglebone board

Tags: beagleboneblack, uart

I have enabled UART1 port in beaglebone board with the baud rate of 115200,8N1 specifications. Also I have connected beaglebone UART port to external PC.

In this PC serial port,I have set baud rate as 115200 and 8N1 specification.

While sending data to PC from beaglebone board, PC can receive the character correctly. But sending data to beaglebone board from PC, beaglebone can correctly read only from character ***a to n***. After these characters, that is ***o to z*** it can read as ***'abcdef...***.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What sort of Port are you using on the PC side?

Comment: I'm using FTDI cable to connect beaglebone UART port and PC.